# Connecting to a database in visual studio 2010 using c# credentials

Tags: asp.net

I'm pretty new to c# asp.net etc so bear with me :)
I've been looking on the internet for the right syntax so I can connect to my database which is on my computer.

I've tried this:

```
 SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;" +
                                               "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                               "database=mmcinfo.mdf;");
```

But i get an error on the myConnection.Open(); saying:

> SqlException was unhandled by user code A network-related or
>   instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to
>   SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify
>   that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to
>   allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 -
>   Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I know im doing something wrong in calling the right database/server etc but i havent got a clue how to fix this.

Comment: Visual studio 2010 have server explorer. Trying to connect the database by that windows to make confirm that your connectionstring is valid.

Comment: How can i do that exactly, as i said i'm pretty new. I have added the database to the server explorer. but i don't know where to go from there.

Comment: check this thread http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/7f238986-ea4a-434d-9b32-986f9c80c624

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after a couple of weeks i found out its not the connectionstring, as many of you suggested.
The sql server seems to act like a user on windows, which needs permissions to access files. In my case these weren't set correctly..

Answer (score 0):

Are you using SQL Express? If so the connection string might need to be localhost\sqlexpress

Comment: I believe i do it does show up in the connectionstring i just found, although just putting in your suggestion doesnt seem to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `.mdf` from the connection string

```
 SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection("server=localhost;" +
                                           "Trusted_Connection=yes;" +
                                           "database=mmcinfo;");
```

You can also use the server explored to get/verify the right connection

### UPDATE

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=./SQLEXPRESS;
            AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\Tim\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\App_Data\mmcinfo.mdf;
            Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
```

Or better still for portability since the db file is in your web app folder

```
SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=./SQLEXPRESS;
            AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\mmcinfo.mdf;
            Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
```

Comment: Having checked the connectionstring it still gives the same error. I switched what i found with the previous string. "AttachDbFilename=C:/Users/Tim/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/WebApplication2/WebApplication2/App_Data/mmcinfo.mdf;"+
                "Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");

Comment: In Visual Studio, Click on View, then Server Explorer if it's not visible. In Server Explorer, right click on Data Connections and select Add Connection. Select your database and click on Advanced... button. Copy the data source from below the dialog box

Comment: Did what you said, had too edit what showed up in the box though. The backslashes arent appreciated, as wel as the quotations. I put in this "Data Source=./SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:/Users/Tim/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/WebApplication2/WebApplication2/App_Data/mmcinfo.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True"        But it still won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Create anywhere a .udl extension file and double click it, follow the wizard to connect to ur database. When u re done, drag the file to notepad copy and paste the connection string on ur program. Bingo

Comment: I'm trying your idea atm but it seems i can't even test my connection. "Microsoft data link error". "Test connection failed because of an error in initializing provider. [DBNETLIB][ConnectionOpen(Connect()).]SQL server does noet exist or access denied"

Comment: Good, we re going somewhere. I can see u re using windows authentication, re u sure u have access to this mmcinfo database?

Comment: But i do get a connectionstring in the file, i copy pasted it into my sqlconnection, but no bingo. It says provider is not a supported keyword. SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(@"Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Integrated Security=SSPI;Persist Security Info=False;Initial Catalog=test;Data Source=TIM-BLACKY;Initial File Name=C:/Users/Tim/Documents/Visual Studio 2010/Projects/WebApplication2/WebApplication2/App_Data/mmcinfo.mdf");.

Comment: It is worthless trying to access from ur program. Be sure u will be able to access from the .udl first. Small steps ..

Comment: I can get into the database file via Visual studio 2010 with the server explorer

Comment: Remove Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;from connection string once u re using sqlclient to access db